# Css clip-path with no gap in between

Tags: css, clip-path

I am trying to apply `clip-path` on three items which are aligned next to each other. Since paths are calculating the space between each other based on the non-clipped `div` shape, there is an unwanted gap. In the code below when I apply the commented styles in `.class2` I get a close result of what I want, but then it's no longer responsive. Any other way to get the similar result with a more suitable approach ?

https://codepen.io/SpoyrazY/pen/erbKXx

HTML

```
<div class="class1">
    <h1>1</h1>
</div>
<div class="class2">
    <h1>2</h1>
</div>
<div class="class3">
    <h1>3</h1>  
</div>
```

CSS

```
.class1{
  background-image:url(https://dummyimage.com/600x400/66ccff/fff&text=+);
  width: 33.33333333%;
  height: 400px;
  float: left;
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 85% 100%, 0 100%);
  clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 85% 100%, 0 100%);
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
}
.class2{
  background-image:url(https://dummyimage.com/600x400/66ff66/fff&text=+);
  width: 33.33333333%;
  height: 400px;
  float: left;
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(15% 0, 100% 0%, 85% 100%, 0%, 100%);
  clip-path: polygon(15% 0, 100% 0%, 85% 100%, 0% 100%);
  /*
  margin-left: -90px;
  margin-right: -90px;
  width: 42.7%;
   -webkit-clip-path: polygon(12% 0, 100% 0%, 85% 100%, 0%, 100%);
  clip-path: polygon(12% 0, 100% 0%, 88% 100%, 0% 100%);
  */
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
}
.class3{
  background-image:url(https://dummyimage.com/600x400/ff99ff/fff&text=+);
  width: 33.33333333%;
  height: 400px;
  float: left;
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(15% 0, 100% 0, 100% 100%, 0 100%);
  clip-path: polygon(15% 0, 100% 0, 100% 100%, 0 100%);
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This happens due to `clip-path`. you can achieve your result by setting `scale` in a custom class. so your `html` will be like this

```
<div class="class1 block">
    <h1>1</h1>
</div>
<div class="class2 block">
    <h1>2</h1>
</div>
<div class="class3 block">
    <h1>3</h1>  
</div>
```

Add some lines of `css`

```
.block {
   transform: scale(1.35);
   transform-origin: top;
}
```

working fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/ckcmj2es/2/)

Comment: I've already tried it if you check the commented code ( i used px instead of %) but then you get a gap in right side of the elements